# Options request has created while sending GET request with headers - Angular7

Tags: javascript, angular, header, cors, interceptor

[image]

When i send GET request along with headers(see username in the image),a Options request triggered by Angular instead of sending GET request that cause my request fail but it works fine without headers. I have highlihted the Request method as you can see it is Options but it should be GET.

```
this._http
      .get(url,{ headers: {  'userName':'john' }} )
```

Answer (score 2):

From your image it appears the server is only returning allow-headers for Content-Type & Accept.

Try adding ‘username’ to this list.

Note the OPTIONS request occurs as a result of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (and not Angular specifically).

Hope this helps.